# How can I correctly evaluate this value in my toy language

Tags: haskell, gadt

I'm making a toy language where I want to be able to do arithmetic operations on both Floats and Integers with the same constructors, like so (minimal example provided below).

```
data Expr a where
  NumberConst :: Number a -> Expr (Number a)
  Mul         :: Expr (Number n) -> Expr (Number n) -> Expr (Number n)

data family Number :: * -> *
data instance Number Integer = NumInt Integer deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
data instance Number Float   = NumFloat Float deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

class (Eq a, Ord a, Num a) => SquanchyNum a where

  toDigit  :: Number a -> a
  divide :: Number a -> Number a -> a
  mul    :: Number a -> Number a -> a
  sub    :: Number a -> Number a -> a
  add    :: Number a -> Number a -> a

instance SquanchyNum Integer where

  toDigit  (NumInt x)            = x
  divide (NumInt x) (NumInt y) = x `div` y
  mul    (NumInt x) (NumInt y) = x * y
  sub    (NumInt x) (NumInt y) = x - y
  add    (NumInt x) (NumInt y) = x + y

instance SquanchyNum Float where

  toDigit  (NumFloat x)                = x
  divide (NumFloat x) (NumFloat y) = x / y
  mul    (NumFloat x) (NumFloat y) = x * y
  sub    (NumFloat x) (NumFloat y) = x - y
  add    (NumFloat x) (NumFloat y) = x + y


eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (NumberConst a) = a
eval (Mul a b) = (eval a) `mul` (eval b) <-- this line makes the problem visible
```

in ghci I get the following error

```
*Main> :r
[2 of 3] Compiling Lib              ( /home/michael/git/brokensquanchy/src/Lib.hs, 
 interpreted )

/home/michael/git/brokensquanchy/src/Lib.hs:45:18: error:
   • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: n ~ Number n
     Expected type: a
     Actual type: n
• In the expression: (eval a) `mul` (eval b)
  In an equation for ‘eval’: eval (Mul a b) = (eval a) `mul` (eval b)
• Relevant bindings include
    b :: Expr (Number n)
      (bound at /home/michael/git/brokensquanchy/src/Lib.hs:45:13)
    a :: Expr (Number n)
      (bound at /home/michael/git/brokensquanchy/src/Lib.hs:45:11)
|
45 | eval (Mul a b) = (eval a) `mul` (eval b)
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, one module loaded.
```

*however* when I try the following in ghci by hand it works

```
(eval (NumberConst (NumInt 6))) `mul` (eval (NumberConst (NumInt 2)))
12
```

This leads me to believe I am not providing enough detail in my type signature for eval. What's the solution?

Edit - I don't think I'm either approaching this problem correctly or explaining it clearly.

Addressing luqui's question

> You are already marking the type with the `a` -- you can deduce from the type which constructor it will be -- the constructor does nothing for you. Why not banish `Number a` from this source file, just replacing it with `a` everywhere?

Okay, let's do that with `NumberConst`

```
data Expr a where
  NumberConst :: a -> Expr a
```

Now I can do this

```
:t NumberConst ("bad code") 
NumberConst ("bad code") :: Expr [Char]
```

I don't want to be able to do that.

So, I need a way to **(1)** enforce that my arithmetic constructors can only have an `Int` or a `Float` **(2)** avoid duplicate constructors, one for both Int and Float. I should be able to use arithmetic constructors on either `Int` or `Float`. **(3)** be able to know if it's an `Int` or a `Float` so that I can handle division.

A data family plus type class is the way I thought to be able to accomplish that. If that's not necessary, I'm all for a simpler approach. I just don't know what that is.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to accomplish with the `Number` data-family. It doesn't really do anything useful. Why not just store the numbers as they are, instead of wrapping them in what's essentially a pretentious newtype?

Comment: @leftroundabout it's a (possibly wrong) response to how to deal with `div` and `/`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have not included the div code in the problem, but I wanted to have one operation for both Float and Integer.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If I want both `Float` and `Integer` , but don't use data families (or some other mechanism), I'm not sure how to avoid a separate constructor for each.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard Wouldn't the type class alone (without the data family) be enough for that? Maybe I'm not understanding something here

Comment: You are already marking the type with the `a` -- you can deduce from the type which constructor it will be -- the constructor does nothing for you.  Why not banish `Number a` from this source file, just replacing it with `a` everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Okay, let's do that with NumberConst
>
> ```
> data Expr a where
>  NumberConst :: a -> Expr a
> ```
>
> Now I can do this
>
> ```
> :t NumberConst ("bad code")
> NumberConst ("bad code") :: Expr [Char]
> ```
>
> I don't want to be able to do that.

I see. Here we're running a bit into a philosophical question: *what is the point of strong types?* Many programmers will say, *to reject malformed programs*. That's certainly an advantage, but Haskell has long followed the direction of what Simon Peyton Jones calls *sexy types*: a type signature should never just *forbid* things, but rather guide you so the program is automatically correct.

In other words, restricting what types can be in `NumberConst` just for the sake of preventing `NumberConst "bad code"` is not sexy. Instead, you should just require the property that is actually needed. That doesn't require any data families, just simply a typeclass. It seems you basically just require `Num` / `Fractional`, except with a division that doubles as `div` for integral and `/` for floating types. (Which is maybe not such a good idea BTW, but let's go with it.)

```
class Num a => Divisible a where
  divide :: a -> a -> a
instance Divisible Int where divide = div
instance Divisible Float where divide = (/)

data Expr a where
  NumberConst :: Divisible a => a -> Expr a
  Mul         :: Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n
```

This constraint is enough to prove that every non-infinite `Expr a` fulfills `Divisible a`. When you implement `eval` you'll find that GHC refuses to acknowledge that. As a solution you can either simply add the constraint also to `Mul`

```
  Mul         :: Divisible n => Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n
```

...which is strictly speaking redundant, but that may not matter; or you can implement a helper function in continuation-passing style that extracts the proof from the expression:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

evalCPS :: Expr a -> (Divisible a => a -> r) -> r
evalCPS (NumberConst n) q = q n
evalCPS (Mul x y) q = x `evalCPS` \x' -> q $ x' * eval y

eval :: Expr a -> a
eval = evalCPS id
```

---

> **(3)** be able to know if it's an `Int` or a `Float` so that I can handle division.

The above solution doesn't do that. In fact, anybody could add more instances later on. If you don't want that, if you really want to allow only `Int` and `Float` exactly and want to be able to find out which one it is, then I'd suggest you *do* use separate constructors, but only for the constants:

```
data Expr a where
  IntConst :: Int -> Expr Int
  FloatConst :: Float -> Expr Float
  Mul :: Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
```

Now, you can again use a CPS version of `eval` which allows for different continuation depending on whether it's `Int` or `Float`:

```
evalCPSMono :: Expr a -> (Int -> r) -> (Float -> r) -> r
evalCPSMono (IntConst i) qI _ = qI i
evalCPSMono (FloatConst w) _ qF = qF w
evalCPSMono (Mul x y) qI qF
   = evalCPSMono x (\x' -> qI $ x' * eval y)
                   (\x' -> qF $ x' * eval y)
```

Alternatively, you could express the restriction to exactly two types with a *closed type family*.

```
type NumberAllower a where
  NumberAllower Int = Int
  NumberAllower Float = Float
  NumberAllower a = Void

data Expr a where
  NumberConst :: NumberAllower a -> Expr a
  ...
```

This prevents anybody from writing `NumberConst "bad code"`. But what it does *not* do is letting you find out what particular type is contained in an `Expr`. You'd end up having to require that manually from the outside anyway. Not sexy.

An alternative that still has only a single `NumberConst` constructor, but does let you obtain the exact type, is this (which is perhaps what you tried to write in the first place):

```
data Number a where
  It'sInt :: Int -> Number Int
  It'sFloat :: Float -> Number Float

data Expr a where
  NumberConst :: Number a -> Expr a
  Mul :: Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
```

This is in practice

Comment: "to reject malformed programs" <-- yes this is what I was taught. I'm going to run with the new perspective you gave me and see where it goes.